# Does "entlang" go with dative or accusative?

Tags: preposition

I found that *entlang* could be followed by accusative but also by dative.
On Duden it reads in the grammar section:

> *Präposition; bei Nachstellung mit Akkusativ, selten (aber noch schweizerisch) mit Dativ; bei Voranstellung mit Genitiv, seltener mit Dativ, veraltet mit Akkusativ*

I can´t understand which one of the cases would be the best.
Which one do you think is more common? Does it make any difference in the meaning or is it maybe that one sounds more old that the other? Is a case maybe more common in Germany and another in Austria?

In this example, what would you choose?

> Ich fahre eine Zeit lang entlang der Münzgrabenstraße.
>   Ich fahre eine Zeit lang entlang die Münzgrabenstraße

Comment: In my ears "der" is the only correct way (northern Germany).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to, say, [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/entlang): If you use the preposition *entlang* before the noun ('vorgestellt'), use genitive:

> Entlang des Rheins sind …

If you choose the reverse order ('nachgestellt'), use accusative:

> Den Rhein entlang sind …

Dative is rarely used (never heard of it). Thus, your example would be:

> Ich fahre eine Zeit lang die Münzgrabenstraße entlang.
>   Ich fahre eine Zeit lang entlang der Münzgrabenstraße.

But of course, since *Straße* is feminine, you cannot detect whether it's dative or genitive.

Although, it's maybe worth considering [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dem%20Fluss%20entlang%2C%20entlang%20des%20Flusses%2C%20den%20Fluss%20entlang&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdem%20Fluss%20entlang%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Centlang%20des%20Flusses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cden%20Fluss%20entlang%3B%2Cc0), where the not so rare occurrence of the use of dative for the noun *Fluss* is illustrated.

[image]

Comment: How do I tell the [präposition](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/entlang_seitlich_zuseiten), the [adverv](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/entlang_laengs_seitwaerts) and the [präfix](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/entlang_) apart?

Comment: @kirelagin how do you distinguish *the* singular and *the* plural in English?

Comment: I am not sure how this is related, but most of the time plurals end with an “s”. In essence, my question is this: e.g. in “Ich fahre die Straße entlang” how do I tell if “enltang” is a postposition or a part of “entlangfahren”? I guess, it can’t be an adverb here as, according to PONS, the adverb “entlang” goes with preposition “an” (“Ich fahre an der Straße entlang”, right?).

Comment: @kirelagin I don't know how this comment is related to this question either. But, I see your comment now is interesting (even though I don't see how the meaning of your example-sentence differs when *entlang* takes the prefix role from its postpositon's role). But you can always open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Hier gibt es verschiedene Varianten und man muss hier unterscheiden, was in der gesprochenen Sprache wirklich gebraucht wird und was in geschriebener so alles vorkommt.
Ein weiteres Problem ist, dass "entlang" vor- und nachgestellt werden kann. Ich bin ein süddeutscher Sprecher und für mich ist die geläufigste gesprochene Variante

- wir fuhren am Rhein entlang,

Und auch

- ich ging die Straße entlang.

Hier dürfte es aber je nach Sprecher und Region einige Unterschiede geben.

Comment: Du verwendest im ersten Beispiel das [Adverb entlang](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/entlang_laengs_seitwaerts), gefragt war aber nach der Präposition.

Comment: Bist du dir da sicher, dass das nachgestellte "entlang" ein Adverb ist. Unabhängig davon, ich verstehe die Frage im Sinne von wie wird das Funktionswort entlang gebraucht.

Comment: Ich bin mir jedenfalls sehr sicher, dass dein Beispiel äquivalent ist zu dem vom Duden, und ich vertraue mal darauf, dass die das richtig einsortiert haben. Wäre es eine Präposition, hätte der Rhein hier gleich zwei davon, denn an/am ist ja auch noch da. Ansonsten: [Wikipedia zufolge](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synsemantikum) gehören zwar Präpositionen zu den Funktionswörtern, aber nicht Adverben. Auch zu diesem Ansatz passt also dein Beispiel nicht.