# Relative clauses with postpositions. Nebensätze mit nachgestellten Präpositionen

Tags: preposition, relative-clause

Take, for sake of concreteness, the preposition *entlang* (see also this [related question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/20551/1691)).

At least, two uses are possible:

> **Genitive preposition**:   Entlang des Flusses gibt es …
> **Accusative postposition**: Den Fluss entlang gibt es …

<sup>(I ignored the dative-variant since it is rare and it's something don't feel confortable with. But the answer explains it all.)</sup>

As for a relative clause, is genitive the only option?

> der Fluss, entlang dessen es … gibt, …

or is it also possible with the accusative variant? like:

> der Fluss, den entlang es … gibt, … <sup>(which somehow sounds awkward)</sup>.

I guess the same rule would hold for other postpositions, like *wegen*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Entlang* takes either genitive, accusative or dative. It's accusative or rarely dative if following the substantive:

> Es gibt Bäume den Fluss entlang.
>   Es gibt Bäume dem Fluss entlang.

And genitive or dative if preceding the substantive:

> Es gibt Bäume entlang des Flusses.
>   Es gibt Bäume entlang dem Fluss.

Another variation is:

> Es gibt Bäume am Fluss entlang.

In a relative clause it looks like this

> Der Fluss, entlang dessen es Bäume gibt. (genitive)
>   Der Fluss, entlang dem es Bäume gibt. (dative)
>   Der Fluss, an dem entlang es Bäume gibt.

Using accusative sounds indeed odd in your example. I believe reason is the "es gibt"-structure. From a grammatical point of view, I don't see any reason why it should be wrong. Here's a different example, which is absolutely fine:

> Man fährt im Schiff den Fluss entlang.
>   Der Fluss, den man im Schiff entlang fährt.

So, nothing wrong with:

> Der Fluss, den entlang es Bäume gibt. (accusative)
>   Der Fluss, dem entlang es Bäume gibt. (dative)